# OkHttp causes an NoClassDefFoundError no matter the dependency versions

Tags: java, okhttp, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to use an API via RapidAPI to get various basketball stats. The following error points at the OkHttpClient declaration line below. I've tried adding multiple releases of Kotlin-stdlib JAR files to the project's build path (I'm using Eclipse) and get the same error running this test request. I currently have Kotlin v1.4.10 added to the build path and see the class named in the error message in the list of referenced libraries. I am also using the OkHttp v4.91 and Okio v2.7.0 libraries, as stated in the OkHttp changelog. Also, I didn't build with Maven or Gradle.

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/players/firstName/lebron")
        .get()
        .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", rAPIKey)
        .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", host)
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

   System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Yielding this error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker
at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.kt:63)
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.kt:1073)
at CourtVisionary.main(CourtVisionary.java:39)
```

What could be causing this issue? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Fixed my own issue. I created a new project, copied and pasted my java files over. Added the JAR files, and got no error when I ran.

Comment: Did you find a solution, facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I started the project over from scratch and copied and pasted all the code into new blank java files. Not ideal if you have a lot of files, I'm sure but it solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own issue. I created a new project, copied and pasted my java files over. Added the JAR files, and got no error when I ran.

Comment: For next time, instead of writting it as seprate answer you can instead edit your questions and wrote your update.